# Why does all selected QGraphicsItem not receive mouseMove event?

Tags: qt, events, qgraphicsitem

I have several QGraphicsItem objects on my custom GraphicsScene. They have different custom types, so some of them have to handle MouseMove event in one way, and other in different way.
When I select some of them and then move selected items only the item that is under the mouse cursor receive MouseMove event but other items does not. I have to make some additional actions in MyCustomItemClass::mouseMoveEvent when moving is started. 
So why does the other items not receive the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I would not handle these actions in `MyCustomItemClass::mouseMoveEvent` because this is only executed when the mouse moves on top of that particular item as you already stated.

Instead I'd subclass the `mouseMoveEvent` in the `scene` to check which items are selected and execute the related method in these items. Of course you have to be careful to only move them relatively to their original position according to the relative mouse movement.

Comment: But for items of different classes that situated on scene I have to perform different actions when moving begin. And these classes may not have a common base class. The way to check the type of items on the scene is not good because we have to cast item on scene to specific class type. How can I handle this?

Comment: What is the problem with casting? How many different classes do you have that it is too much effort?

Comment: Even if there are four different classes, casting is not the best solution, because of huge if-else sequences.

Comment: I'd probably use a `switch` and with only four `cases` it is definately not huge

Comment: By the way, do you think creating of new class with one pure virtual method (like interface class) will a good solution? In this case every requested graphics class can be derived from this class and define its custom behaviour in such overload method.

Comment: Defining a common base class is always a good solution if the desired derived classes have enough in common justifying it

Comment: There will be only one pure virtual method in common base class that must have unique definition in every derived graphics class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a group of items and then move them all at once, you can add them to a [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemgroup.html) during the select and then move the group as a single object, which will move all the items in the group.

Comment: But also I need to perform moving of any item in group separately. QGraphicsItemGroup does not give this possibility - during moving some item from group all grouped items always will move with this item.

Comment: If multiple items are selected, add to group and move. When deselection occurs, remove the items from the group.